# 'colors'.dartundefined_named_parameter in flutter

Tags: flutter, syntax-error

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(    //inside body
    gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: [Colors.pink, Colors.yellow],
    ),
),
```

The app is working completely fine and debug console is clean(really).But at `colors:` there's always a red squiggly line and it is saying:
*The named parameter 'colors' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'colors'.dartundefined_named_parameter)*
When I hover over it.
I am doing it in VScode by the way and it shows no quickfix available.
Also in my original project it is completely fine this error occurs when I clone the repository(from github) in a different folder.
I wanted to know is there something I should do when cloning to prevent this. Also will there be any impact in the long run because I don't want it to have any errors in later phase.

PS: I have not touched .gitignore at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element type List of MaterialAccentColor can't be assigned to the list type 'Color'.

Try

```
gradient: LinearGradient(
    colors:[
      Color(0xfff3c6a5),
      Color(0xffedb98a),
    ],
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically nothing but a major problem. If you are using VS Code, please restart the editor. I also faced the same problem but I finally fixed it.

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
               gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Color.fromRGBO(215, 117, 255, 1).withOpacity(0.5),
                  Color.fromRGBO(255, 188, 117, 1).withOpacity(0.9),
                ],
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                stops: [0, 1],
           ),
      ),
```